# CUPS server is not accessible at privateip:631

Tags: amazon-web-services, cups

I have deployed a VM instance in AWS lightsail ubuntu 16.03 and I am newbie, I have no clue how to make cups accessible
when I navigate to publicip:631 it works it open gui interface but when I click on add printer it navigates me to privateip:631 which is not accessible I want to use add printer functionality please help sorry for my bad English

add printer page forcing me to redirect
[image]

public ip accessible cups page
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to print from a cloud server?

Comment: Yes, from AWS created a vm instance and hosted flask app

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert there, but I would recommend to read the article at https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017214

You should modify the config file (e.g. /etc/cups/cupsd.conf) to use public IP instead of private.

e.g.

```
Listen <publicip>:631
```

Comment: I have done this , doesn't work  I can see cups web interface  on public ip but when I click add printer it redirect me to <private ip> : 631 ultimately saying this site cannot be reached :( I think there need some sort of tunneling required but I have no idea if u have some tutorial that would help. Thanks for replying and for ur effort 